# How to append element and get its selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a `div` and afterwards to be able to select it. Can my code be optimized?

JS:

```
$someEle.append("<div><span>5</span><span>€</span></div>");
var $newELE = $someEle.find('div');
```

Comment: you could give the appended thing an id if you are only appending it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the elements first, that way they are easily accessible both before and after you append them

```
var div   = $('<div />'),
    span1 = $('<span />', {text : '5'}),
    span2 = $('<span />', {text : '€'});

$someEle.append( div.append( span1, span2 ) );

div.css('color', 'red'); // use element
```

Comment: Performancewise the OP will never notice a difference, creating elements is fast regardless of what way one does it.

Comment: Well, then what is the question about?

Comment: @Regent - Who knows !